# How to split the below string in python as below?

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, split

String examples --> Expected output

```
"    1     1    1-1 SOME MESSAGE HERE" --> ['1','1','1-1','SOME MESSAGE HERE']

"   71    91    1-1 SOME MESSAGE HERE" --> ['71','91','1-1','SOME MESSAGE HERE']

"  171   191    1-1 SOME MESSAGE HERE" --> ['171','191','1-1','SOME MESSAGE HERE']

" 1171  1191    1-1 SOME MESSAGE HERE" --> ['1171','1191','1-1','SOME MESSAGE HERE']
```

Comment: Use .split with a maxsplit arg https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In Python 2.7

```
x = "    1     1    1-1 SOME MESSAGE HERE"
y = x.split(None, 3)
print (y)  # ['1', '1', '1-1', 'SOME MESSAGE HERE']
```

#### In Python 3

```
x = "    1     1    1-1 SOME MESSAGE HERE"
y = x.split(maxsplit=3)
print (y)  # ['1', '1', '1-1', 'SOME MESSAGE HERE']
```